# How to make a parameter follows the waveform of another parameter - C code

Tags: c

In C code, it gets an input from hardware (Altera Nios II system), this input "vref" is a sinusoidal waveform. Edit: In Altera Quartus in vhdl, it generates a sinusoidal waveform for "vref" which becomes the input to the C code. (C code is used to program the processor NIos II)

In C code, I have another input say "vref_new", "vref_new" is a variable where its value keeps changing based on some calculations. Edit: "vref_new" is the new value for amplitude "vref"

Edit: What should I do so that when I plot the "vref_new" as an output on a graph, the "vref_new" will be plotted as sinuisoial waveform instead of just amplitude? The frequency and sample rate of "vref_new" should follow exactly of the "vref". vref is a sinewave, vref_new is just the updated amplitude to replace the amplitude in vref.

If I know the amplitude of "vref" to be a constant say 40, then I can do something like this:

```
vref_new= vref_new*vref*(1/40);
```

but the trouble is I don't know the amplitude of "vref" as it is not constant.

Edit: the reason to divide by 40 is so that I get the correct amplitude given by "vref_new".

Edit: vref is a sine wave generated from vhdl custom block in Quartus, and vref_new is just a value represents the amplitude of sine wave.

vref is a varying sinusoidal signal, but the amplitude needs to be updated with vref_new. after the system get the vref, it did some calculations to obtain vref_new, but vref_new is just an amplitude, so how can I plot vref_new to show me a sinusoidal signal?

I apologize if my question sounds stupid....thank you in advance

```
#define vref_base 0x00002220 
int16_t vref=0, vref_new=0;

vref = IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(vref_base);
vref_new = a*b/c; //some calculation
amp_vrefnew=(int16_t)vref;
vref_new = vref_new*vref/amp_vrefnew; //in order to make vref_new follows the sinewave of vref
```

Look at the green line in the image, I still do not get a sinusoidal waveform, green line is the vref_new while black line is the vref

[image]

However, if I do the following by replacing the "amp_vrefnew" with a constant say "3920", I can get a sinusoidal waveform for vref_new,

```
#define vref_base 0x00002220 
int16_t vref=0, vref_new=0;

vref = IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(vref_base);
vref_new = a*b/c; //some calculation
vref_new = vref_new*vref/3920; //in order to make vref_new follows the sinewave of vref
```

Comment: I don't think we'll be able to help you here.

Comment: @staticx Is the question not clear enough? sorry, then I should explain further? or do you think it is not possible?

Comment: Your question is a masterpiece in obfuscation. No, it is not clear enough. Many things are missing, e.g. the types of the variables. When you go to the doctor, say more than *ouch!*

Comment: I have no experience in DSP, and I'm probably not the only one. The current wording of your question leaves me with no idea what "get the shape" means here.

Comment: There is room to improve the question. I think that other people are unsure because you reference some hardware, but your question is not, AFAICT, about accessing the hardware so much as about how to do calculations on values which happen to have been generated by or retrieved from some specific hardware. Your outline calculation suggests that `vref_new` is both an input and an output since you base your calculation on its old value and assign it a new value. How can you determine the range of values that can be returned by `vref`? Do you have multiple values you can look at?  Do you need FFT?

Comment: @Jens, thanks for your comment, I have added some details in the post: vref is a sine wave generated from vhdl custom block in Quartus, and vref_new is just a value represents the amplitude of sine wave

Comment: @Quentin, forgive the newbie mistake... I should say that vref is a sine wave generated from vhdl custom block in Quartus, and vref_new is just a value represents the amplitude of sine wave, so when I plot the graph of  vref_new, I want it to be sine wave

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler , thanks for your comment, vref is a sinewave, vref_new is just the updated amplitude to replace the amplitude in vref. I don't need fft.

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you just included your code in the question.

Comment: This doesn't even appear to be a [C] question.  It appears to be a DSP / signal processing question.

Comment: @abelenky , it is actually just manipulation of parameter instead of dsp/signal processing, forgive me for not stating clear enough, I have made some changes and added some codes and image, thank you

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I have just added the code and image, sorry for the bad formulation of the question

Answer (score 3):

Is the problem that `vref_new` is always zero? That's because 1/40 is zero in C's integer arithmetic.

If `vref_new` is the non-varying amplitude, and `vref` the sinusoidal signal in the range [-1, 1], then

```
x = vref_new * vref;
```

is probably what you want.

Comment: The problem I have is , vref_new is not a sine waveform, but it is just amplitude of sine wave...so ends up when I plot vref_new, I didn't get sinusoidal waveform as wanted

Comment: And which variable would contain the varying sinusoidal signal? Why don't you plot that variable instead?

Comment: vref is a varying sinusoidal signal, but the amplitude needs to be updated with vref_new. after the system get the vref, it did some calculations to obtain vref_new, but vref_new is just an amplitude, so how can I plot vref_new to show me a sinusoidal signal?

Comment: sorry for late reply I just see your edited post. You are right that "vref_new is the non-varying amplitude, and vref the sinusoidal signal ", This is what I want, just that the vref is not in the range of [-1 1], it can be any value in the range of [-50 50], and I do not know the value and it is not constant

Comment: I have added the code but I still do not get a sine waveform, I attached the waveform above, thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your question I assume that the input signal `vref` is a sinusoid with an unknown magnitude and you want to know the magnitude as soon as you start receiving the input signal.

[image]

The blue line marks the point at which you start receiving the signal from your sensor and you want to know the magnitude.

If I'm right then here's something you can do.

Assume the input signal to be

[image]

where [image] and [image] are unknown.

[image]

[image]

You can use these three equations to solve for [image] and [image]. The derivative terms can be calculated by observing first few readings in the sequence and then you can use the calculated magnitude as you wish.

Here are the final results:

[image]

[image]

at any time [image]

To plot it on a graph you need to know the time difference between two consecutive readings from the sensor. Then you can plot

```
x = [t0, t1, t2, ...]
y = vref normalized by A calculated as above
```